# MapKit .mapStyle pointsOfInterest with selectable .mapStyle

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I used an example found here to enable user selectable mapStyle:

```
    private var selectedMapStyle: MapStyle {
        return switch(mapType) {
        case 0: .standard
        case 1: .hybrid
        case 2: .imagery
        default: .standard
        }
    }
    @State private var mapType: Int = 0
```

This works great for adding a Button to toggle between hybrid and standard mapStyles. But adding a pointsOfInterest filter does not.

This works:

`.mapStyle(selectedMapStyle)`

and this works:

`.mapStyle(.standard(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))`

but this doesn't:

`.mapStyle(selectedMapStyle(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))`

The errors are:
"Cannot call value of non-function type 'MapStyle'" and
"Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'excludingAll'"

How do I make the compiler happy for this combo? Thanks!

Added: example code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var selectedMapStyle: MapStyle {
        return switch(mapType) {
        case 0: .standard
        case 1: .hybrid
        case 2: .imagery
        default: .standard
        }
    }
    @State private var mapType: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Map ()
        // this works:
        .mapStyle(selectedMapStyle)
        // this works:
        //.mapStyle(.hybrid(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))
        //this doesn't work:
        //.mapStyle(selectedMapStyle(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))
        Button(action: {
            if mapType == 0 {
                mapType = 1
            } else {
                mapType = 0
            }
        })
        {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "map")
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                Text("Map Style")
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Kushagra I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `selectedMapStyle` is a type of `MapStyle`. However, `.hybrid(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll)` is a function which returns a `MapStyle` with supplied parameters. That's the reason the compiler is throwing an error.

So adding the appropriate function in your switch case instead of the enum works. You can change the `selectedPointsOfInterest` to update the map style.

Here's the code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    private var selectedMapStyle: MapStyle {
        return switch(mapType) {
        case 0: .standard(pointsOfInterest: selectedPointsOfInterest)
        case 1: .hybrid(pointsOfInterest: selectedPointsOfInterest)
        case 2: .imagery
        default: .standard
        }
    }
    
    @State private var mapType: Int = 0
    @State private var selectedPointsOfInterest: PointOfInterestCategories = .excludingAll

    var body: some View {
        Map ()
        .mapStyle(selectedMapStyle)
        Button(action: {
            if mapType == 0 {
                mapType = 1
            } else {
                mapType = 0
            }
        }) {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "map")
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                Text("Map Style")
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```